# How to read PHP generated json in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: json, hash, ruby-1.8.7

I have a hashes of JSON generated by php application , which i want to read in my rails controller.
Is there any way can i convert this json in hashes again , so that i can able to read it.

```
json_from_php = "{'coms':[{'com':{'title':'kk dd','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=02'}},{'com':{'title':'sdsdsdsd dsds','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=06'}},{'com':{'title':'PHPTVDB: Using PHP ','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=4'}},{'com':{'title':'Plugins','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=08'}},{'com':{'title':'vvv','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=2218'}},{'com':{'title':'dsds sdsds ','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=12'}},{'com':{'title':'Represent ','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=5'}},{'com':{'title':'ZebraTable','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?page_id=4'}},{'com':{'title':'rr Plugin','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=2'}},{'com':{'title':'dasd asdasd !','guid':'http:\/\/tes.name\/?p=1'}}]}"

#ss = JSON.parser(json_from_php)
```

> error info :
>   JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '{'coms':[{'com':{

Reference https://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Answer (score 0):

```
ss = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_from_php) solved this issue
```